# How to add an session value to a custom webforms for markters save action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7

I'm using Sitecore with WebForms For Marketers (WFFM). Between the Content Delivery Server (CDS) and Content Management Server (CMS) is a web service. I have written a custom save action.

I'm looking for a manner to send a session value from the CDS to the CMS server without a custom hidden field. It must be friendly for the Content Editor. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Jordy

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this and the only way I could get it working was with a hidden field.

If you put a Field type of hidden field on the form, in the Save action you can set the hidden fields value to be the value from session and then the save to database action will pass on the data to the web service.

I tried looking at adding extra fields to the collection of fields that goes to the database but the classes I needed were protected.

Would be good to hear if anyone else has a nifty way of getting round this issue though.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to add the hidden session field automaticly to all (WFFM) forms?

Comment: Not as far as I am aware. Good post on hidden fields here http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/02/18/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-send-email-with-attachment-save-action/